# Data Requirements for Security Review to test Web Services in a package

Tags: webservices, soap, security-review

I have a package that I am trying to get through security review. The package is really an API layer that other packages rely on, so it doesn't have a UI you can submit calls through - just global classes other packages can invoke to make requests to the SOAP web services provided by the package.

I got back an email from Security Review team saying the following:
"We would need sample http request or good data for the below methods of web service to test individual methods."

Anyone know what that looks like in practice? Should I provide sample code that they could run in the Dev Console that will invoke my global methods that will in turn trigger the callouts? Or are they looking for sample XML they could paste into something like SOAP UI and see what is going on? Anyone navigated something similar through the review process?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would be sample XML that they could use in SOAP UI. Please also give them any information necessary for them to craft their own calls.

Comment: Thanks. In the email, it sounded like they just wanted the param string that gets passed into each method - but do you think they also want the whole SOAP envelope that gets with each callout?

Comment: Yeah, just give them a trace. They are going to try to make their own calls, so the easier you make it for them, the faster the review.